# как удалить воспроизведенный mp3 файл

Tags: python

```
def say(text):
    voice = gTTS(text, lang="ru")
    sound = "audio_" + str(random.randint(0, 20)) + ".wav"
    voice.save(sound)
    playSound(sound)
    print("Ассистент: ", text)
    sound.close()#пишет мол str object has no attribute close, но ведь я пытаюсь файл удалить.
    os.remove(sound)



#непосредственно поиск и запуск аудиофайла
def playSound(myFile):
    mus = pyglet.media.load("C:/Users/Edward/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/" + myFile)
    mus.play()
    pyglet.clock.schedule_once(exiterFromPlaySound, mus.duration)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Проблема в том, что я хочу удалять mp3 файлы после их воспроизведения.
Я прописал os.remove(sound) и пошло поехало:
Первый аудиофайл оно генерирует-воспроизводит-удаляет, второй генерирует-воспроизводит- и не удаляет при этом пишет, [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'audio_18.wav'
я прописал sound.close(), чтоб наверняка файл закрыть, но пишет мол str object has no attribute close. Гуглил не помогло.

Comment: os.remove(sound) - прописал. 
[WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'audio_59185.wav'

Comment: Но ведь, `sound` - это строка. Конечно, у нее нет метода `close()`

Comment: Но я же в ```sound```  поместил аудиофайл? Или как мне тогда обратиться к самому файлу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но я же в sound поместил аудиофайл? Или как мне тогда обратиться к самому файлу?

Нет. В `sound` у вас хранится имя файла `"audio_" + str(random.randint(0, 20)) + ".wav"`, которое вы передаете в `pyglet.media.load(...)`.

Чтобы самостоятельно управлять открытиеми закрытием файла, начните с чего-то такого:

```
filename = "C:/Users/Edward/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/audio_" + str(random.randint(0, 20)) + ".wav"
f = open(filename, "rb")
mus = pyglet.media.load("", f)
mus.play()
f.close()
....
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло! Тема закрыта!

Comment: @Nofate Но лучше всё-таки открывать файлы через `with`, чтобы они закрывались автоматом по выходе из блока кода.

Comment: @CrazyElf Само собой. Но я не хотел делать пример, где управление дескриптором снова скрыто за абстракцией.

Comment: @Nofate Понятно. Просто всегда сразу в глаза бросается. В 2022 году вручную файлы закрывать... )

Comment: @CrazyElf появилась необходимость закрывать файл автоматом, подкинете ссылку на ресурс где можно почитать про открытие mp3 файлов через with?

Comment: @Edward В первом приближении просто открывайте файл так: `with open(...) as f:` и он потом сам закроется. А так ну всё гуглится. Вообще это контекстный менеджер.

Comment: @CrazyElf Благодарю)